# How to fix error: TypeError: elements.classList is undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a class called "blackbackdrop" to every element that has a class called "icon" using classList.
Unfortunately it does not work because of error `TypeError: elements.classList is undefined`

I'm using this code:

```js
function blackBackDropIcon() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");
  elements.classList.add('blackbackdrop');
}
```

Comment: `elements` is a collection - you have to iterate it and set each element, or specify an index - `elements[0].classList`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function blackBackDropIcon() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.add('blackbackdrop');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not jQuery, you can't add a class on all elements by referencing the element list. You have to iterate on all the elements, for example like this:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("icon"))
.foreach(elt => elt.classList.add('blackbackdrop'))
```

Comment: Don't you think this example might be a little too complex for the person who is not able to figure out its an array ?

Comment: It might but I'm not so sure about that. Some users are experienced in JavaScript because of Node programming but don't have in-depth knowledge of how the DOM works. I'd say that a two-line code that almost sounds English when you read it can't be *that* complex.

Answer (score 0):

it returns array so you need to add the class via loop all elements of the array and add one by one.

here is code...

```
function blackBackDropIcon() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");
        for (a = 0; a < elements.length; a++) {
            elements[a].classList.add('blackbackdrop');
        }
    }
```

**Explanation:** 
You Can't give all elements array class directly you can give it via array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I accomplished this task:

```
var topics = document.querySelectorAll(".topic");

    for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
        topics[i].classList.remove('displayed-element');
        topics[i].classList.add('hidden-element');
    }
```