# ClassName of of closest() element returning undefined

Tags: javascript, closest, event-delegation, dom-traversal

I am trying to retrieve the class names (and hence use it) of an element that i am retrieving using the target.closest() method. However when i try to apply **classNames** or even do something using classList method the result comes **undefined**.

I looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047633/how-to-fix-error-typeerror-elements-classlist-is-undefined/56047665) on stackoverflow but the person was using an html collection and by using a single element, his issue was resolved. However my issue remains the same.

```
    const cuisineList = document.querySelector('.cuisinesList');

    cuisineList.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    const hovered = e.target.closest('li');
    console.log("hello", hovered.classNames);
})
```

Sidenote: the "hovered" element in the given code are correctly received. There is no issue in that. The result of the hovered element is the very list element that I want to manipulate.

Comment: `hovered.classNames` should be `hovered.className`, it contains all the classes despite of the property name.

Comment: oh damn, thank you for this :(